# Rman bash script with cronjob

Tags: bash, oracle, rman

i have a rman bash script which works when i execute it (./backup.sh).
but when i use cronjob, it doesn't work.
My scripts is as follows

**backup.sh**

`rman target / @backup.rcv log=rman.log`

**backup.rcv**

`backup format '/backup/rman/backup/%U.arch.rman' filesperset 2 archivelog all delete input; backup format '/backup/rman/backup/%U.datafiles.rman' filesperset 2 incremental level 0 database; backup format '/backup/rman/backup/%U.arch.rman' filesperset 2 archivelog all delete input; backup format '/backup/rman/backup/%U.ctl.rman' current controlfile; delete noprompt obsolete;`

my cronjob looks somthing like this

**crontab -l**

`5 0 * * * /nas_backup/rman/svbo/backup/L0backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

i am very new to this rman and bash script so any help would be appreciated

Comment: You might need to set Oracle environment in your script,  such as ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Or if you have oraenv setup - just execute oraenv in your script.

Comment: The environment in crontab is different from the env you have in your bash.  In your crontab, replace `>/dev/null 2>&1` by `>/tmp/out.log 2>/tmp/err.log`.  This will show you the error when it runs.  Like @Pankaj said, its most probably some env variable missing, or the path for rman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inorder for this to be fixed replace the code in your "L0backup.sh"
with

```
#!/bin/bash
#
export ORACLE_SID=your-sid
export ORACLE_HOME=your-oracle-home
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/rman target / nocatalog  <<EOF
backup format '/nas_backup/rman/backup/%U.arch.rman' filesperset 2 archivelog all delete input;
backup format '/nas_backup/rman/backup/%U.datafiles.rman' filesperset 2 incremental level 0 database;
backup format '/nas_backup/rman/backup/%U.arch.rman' filesperset 2 archivelog all delete input;
backup format '/nas_backup/rman/backup/%U.ctl.rman' current controlfile;
delete noprompt obsolete;
EOF
```

to get your ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME
you can echo it out like

```
#echo $ORACLE_SID
your-sid
# echo $ORACLE_HOME
your-oracle-home
```

next to set your crontab - lets say you want the above file to run every midnight  ([Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/#5_0_*_*_*))

`#crontab -e`

```
5 0 * * * /bin/bash /nas_backup/rman/backup/L0backup.sh  > /nas_backup/rman/backup/rman.log 2>&1
```

if you notice your output gets loged to "rman.log".

furthermore you can now delete your "backup.rcv" file as its no longer being used.

Answer (score 0):

Step 01. Create a backup script with the following content (modified it as your desire)

```
#!/bin/sh 
#
# Run as: oracle
#
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
export ORACLE_HOME=/oradb/oraclebase/dbhome

rman target /  << EOI
  # Allocating channels (should equal number of physical CPU #lscpu)
  ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH1 DEVICE TYPE DISK;
  ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH2 DEVICE TYPE DISK;

  # change into the highest rate compression - required license 
  CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'HIGH' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD FALSE;

  # validate physical existence of backupset & copy
  CROSSCHECK BACKUPSET;
  CROSSCHECK COPY;
  
  # removing metadata of "EXPIRED" info from the catalog
  DELETE NOPROMPT EXPIRED BACKUPSET;
  DELETE NOPROMPT EXPIRED COPY;

  # Backup full database (incremental level 0) on Sunday
  BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 DATABASE FORMAT '/backup/%d_full_level_0_%U.bak';
  #incremental level 1 on the other days not Sunday
  #enabling block change tracking if you want level 1 goes fast
  #BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 DATABASE FORMAT '/backup/%d_full_level_1_%U.bak';

  # Backup archivelog log
  BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET ARCHIVELOG ALL DELETE INPUT FORMAT '/backup/%_ARCHIVE_%U.bak';;

  # Clean obsolete backups depending on setting of retention policy 
  CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
  DELETE NOPROMPT OBSOLETE;

  # Allocated channel will release automatically ;)
  exit

EOI

exit
```

Step 02: Change owner & permission
Step 03: Set crontab job for that script.